# What will happen to node edges after we delete the node in JanusGraph?

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I want to delete a node from a graph in JanusGraph but I don't know what will happen to its edges? Will they be orphaned? or will be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low level details depend on which backend you using. I think most end-up deleting the edges all together.

For the Cassandra backend edges will be tombstoned and will later get cleaned up (more info [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html)). This means that at first the edges will be hidden for a while and later the data records will be removed.

Either way you won't be able to see those edges.

I am not 100% sure for all the other backends.

Comment: I'm not aware of any TinkerPop-enabled graph that orphans edges as a design choice.